# How to anonymise a numeric data attribute, whilst preserving indexability?

Tags: encryption, databases

I would like to (1-way) anonymise some bounded, numeric data attributes (e.g. age, optimistically bounded by 0 and 200), whilst still retaining the ability to use the resulting data in an index for database queries such as `X < 50` or `X BETWEEN 18 AND 30`.

Ideally the anonymisation process would create a new set of values that were ordered but "differently" distributed, such that it is difficult to infer the old attribute values from the anonymised values.

Are there any standard algorithms that provide this capability?

---

My own thoughts are that I could create a function `F`, such that anonymisation is `X -> F(X)`.

When a data record is saved, the relevant attribute values are transformed (the attribute name would be hashed or similarly anonymised).  Query conditions based on the attribute name could then be transformed to query against the revised attribute name and the transformed query values.

I.e. `X in [ 1, 2, 10, 50 ]` becomes `Hash(X) in [ F(1), F(2), F(10), F(50) ]`

So `F` must satisfy:

- `X == Y` implies `F(X) == F(Y)`
- `X < Y` implies `F(X) < F(Y)`
- `X -> F(X)` must be fast to compute

With this in mind, `F` could consist of multiple polynomial functions `F1`, `F2`, ... `Fn`, each covering a sub-range of the bounded range of `X`, such that at the boundary `Xn`, `Fn(Xn) == F(n+1)(Xn)`, such that the distribution of `F(X)` values is sufficiently different from the distribution of `X`.

The set `Fn` would be randomly generated and managed by the "database" layer when the bounded set of values is declared to the database (optionally with sub-range boundaries also declared), and then is transparently applied when data is saved or queries executed.

For a bounded set of positive values (like age above), polynomials with positive coefficients would work (subject to the subrange boundary conditions); for bounded sets that include negative values, polynomials comprising a series of odd powers are required along with positive coefficients.

Where the bounded set of values will be completely covered by the data set (age is again a good example, if the population is large), then the sub-ranges can be reduced to a single value (i.e a different polynomial is used for each integer age).

---

Clearly a significant issue is to determine what "differently distributed" or "sufficiently different" mean, given the requirement for ordered outputs to `F`.

Are there any standard approaches to this problem that meet the orderedness and distribution changes that I require?